# Difference between XM and XM+ receivers?

Tags: frsky, receiver, comparison, frsky-xm

I have seen both XM and XM+ receivers and am wondering which one would be better to get for a micro-drone build. What are the differences in specs? (range, reliability, weight, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Oscar Liang](https://oscarliang.com/frsky-xm-plus-rx/), the XM+:

- Is larger and heavier than XM (*21.5 x 12 x 3.5 mm – 1.6 g*)
- Has diversity antennae, unlike XM
- Has solder pads in addition to pin headers
- Doesn't support Smart Port telemetry
- Has RSSI channel support on a dedicated pad and 16th channel
- Has a wider input voltage range than XM (*3.7v-10v*)

Comment: The XM+ is actually larger and heavier then the XM:

XM – 15.0×10.0x3.5mm – 1.0g
XM+ (plus) – 21.5x12x3.5mm – 1.6g

Comment: @BenWilson Oh, you're right! I read that wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, they are almost the same.

The only difference is that the XM+ has a diversity receiver so will be more reliable. It also weighs slightly more and is slightly larger (though it’s a negligible amount in my opinion).

If it were me, I’d go for the XM+ for the extra peace of mind.